# how to get current login customer invoice list and shipments in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

> Actually i am trying to get current login customer invoice list and
>   shipments and to display it in customer account dashboard custom link.

If anyone have idea please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For, getting the listed invoice of a customer, you have to call order collection and invoice class.

***Magento does not save customer id at invoice table, Magento saves customer ids at sales order table and every invoice related with an order.***

Assume that you add the list of invoice ids at  Customer DashBoard page.

So , create `customer_account_index.xml`  at `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Block\Customer\InvoiceList" name="customer_account_dashboard_invoice" 
        template="{Vendor}_{ModuleName}::order/invoices.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and add below Block at  `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/Block/Customer/InvoiceList`

```
<?php
/**
 * User: Amit Bera
 * Email: dev.amitbera@gmail.com
 */

namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Block\Customer;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class InvoiceList  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected  $invoices;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $orderCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $invoiceCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory $invoiceCollectionFactory ,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->invoiceCollectionFactory = $invoiceCollectionFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    public function getInvoiceList()
    {
       $orders =  $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomerId()
        );
       $orderids = $orders->getColumnValues('entity_id');
       if(count($orderids))
       {
           $this->invoices = $this->invoiceCollectionFactory->create()
               ->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('order_id',['in' => $orderids]);
       }
       return $this->invoices;
    }
    public function getPrintInvoiceUrl($invoice)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('sales/order/printInvoice', ['invoice_id' => $invoice->getId()]);
    }
}
```

Create **invoices.phtml** at `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/template/order/`

and code:

```
<?php $_invoices = $block->getInvoiceList() ?>
<?php foreach ($_invoices as $_invoice): ?>
<div class="order-title">
    <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Invoice #') ?><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_invoice->getIncrementId() ?></strong>
    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPrintInvoiceUrl($_invoice) ?>"
       onclick="this.target='_blank'"
       class="action print">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Print Invoice') ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: invoice print link is not working here

Comment: working for me thanks. But how can i get data from invoices list like Invoice date ,invoice status , tax etc

Comment: Hello, The Invoice link does not work for me either. Can you please advise on what I have done wrong. Thank you.