# Magento 2.4: How to get the Invoice Collection of Logged In Customers?

Tags: collection, custom, invoice, magento2.4

I have to show the invoice collection of logged-in customers in the frontend. I have referred this link [how to get current login customer invoice list and shipments in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246664/how-to-get-current-login-customer) invoice-list-and-shipments-in-magento-2 but when I implement this, I'm getting the below error

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Please help me to get the invoice collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Please replace your phtml

```
<?php $_invoices = $block->getInvoiceList() ?>
<?php if ($_invoices): ?>
<?php foreach ($_invoices as $_invoice): ?>
<div class="order-title">
    <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Invoice #') ?><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_invoice->getIncrementId() ?></strong>
    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPrintInvoiceUrl($_invoice) ?>"
       onclick="this.target='_blank'"
       class="action print">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Print Invoice') ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have replaced the code and I'm not getting any data.

Comment: please check logged in customer have any invoices or not?